# Does the Delta Family have compact support?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

If the delta function is 0 everywhere except at x=0, does this mean for a delta family {${f}_{\alpha}$} it would have compact support for any ${\alpha}$? because I'm assuming each delta distribution in the family will tend to zero as x goes to infinity?

Comment: What is a "delta family"???

Comment: sorry didnt make that clear, a delta family is for any $\alpha$ contained in the space of real number, the limit of ${f}_{\alpha}$ equals the dirac delta distribution as $\alpha$ goes to some number ${\alpha}_{0}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every delta family needs to have compact support. Take for example
$$f_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\pi}} e^{-x^2/\epsilon}\quad(\text{as } \epsilon\to 0).$$

That this is a delta family is shown by
$$
\langle f_\epsilon, \varphi \rangle
= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\pi}} e^{-x^2/\epsilon} \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \{ y = x/\sqrt{\epsilon} \}
= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\pi}} e^{-y^2} \, \varphi(\sqrt{\epsilon} y) \, \sqrt{\epsilon}\,dy \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int e^{-y^2} \, \varphi(\sqrt{\epsilon} y) \, dy
\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int e^{-y^2} \, \varphi(0) \, dy
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int e^{-y^2} \, dy \, \varphi(0) \\
= \varphi(0) = \langle \delta, \varphi \rangle.
$$